# "moreover" vs "likewise" vs "in addittion" vs "furthermore" vs "as well" vs "also", When should I use each one?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, adverbs

While studying I came across this group of adverbs and all seems to mean the same, **is there some rule or common usage to know when to use at least some of them?**

- moreover
- likewise
- in addition
- furthermore
- as well
- also

Comment: "Also" is simplest, and always appropriate. "Likewise" will usually refer to a comparison of *two* things, not a whole group. "Furthermore" is a little more formal, which is good for articles or academic papers. "As well" should usually *not* appear at the beginning of the sentence.

Comment: @lea - That's pretty good general advice; perhaps you could convert that into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you dig in further, you'll be confused. Just learn that more or less, they ***all are the same***...

> likewise **=** in addition **=** also **=** moreover

Refer [Collins Ditionary for the reference](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/likewise?showCookiePolicy=true)

[Furthermore](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/furthermore?showCookiePolicy=true) ;)

> furthermore **=** in addition **=** moreover

*as well* is equal to *[in addition](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/as-well?showCookiePolicy=true)*.

However, though all mean same, *which to use when* comes through reading, and I'm pretty sure that the more you study, the more you learn about it.